# Equative integration term to prove

Tags: calculus

I've find a statement of equation like this:

[image]
I justified the cases that N=1,2,3, which seem to be correct. However, when I was trying to prove it with induction, I failed to reduce the repetitious terms inside.
Thus, is this statement correct and how to prove it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution through inductions:
[image]
(Integration by parts)